# Who doesn’t belong in the group?

Tags: lateral-thinking, chemistry

Identify the ones that are oddballs

B

C

Ba

W

H

Fe

Si

Br

Rn

I

N

O

P

Comment: Enunciating each of them might help you out

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this question? If there are essentially no restrictions on which are the "odd ones out", and Ak19's answer isn't correct, then *what possible thing could a solver do to figure out which of the possibilities you're thinking of?* This seems like "guess what I'm thinking", not a solvable puzzle.

Comment: See the hint I have given

Comment: Hints are not part of the puzzle. Also, there are still many possibilities -- literally *anything* related to pronunciation could be designated the "rule", and those that don't follow it could be called the odd ones out.

Comment: From a chemistry point of view, this is very upsetting. There is practically a large, extensive list of ways to group these elements in ways that can be classed as "oddball". Given the acceptance of Ak19's answer you have opened this large door. How about changing the "chemistry" tag to "language"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If balls represent the atoms or the elements,

> The odd-balls are B, H, Br, I, N, P which have odd number of protons or atomic numbers.

Comment: Not right..listening to them might help

Comment: May be the number of letters in each element name ?

Comment: Listen to the sounds of each of them

Comment: @Uvc Feel free to unaccept mine, if it is not the intended answer : )

Comment: It meets the requirements of oddball..sometimes puzzles like this, you can have couple of unexpected answers which op might not have thought of..

Answer (score 0):

> Answer Given meets the oddball requirement....what I was expecting..based on the sound..P and Ba are the only two that don’t have ending n sound

Comment: While tungsten and iron are the only elements that have a stem change and thus sound very different from their symbol...